# how to handle the overwriting the Upload data in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios5, file-upload, overwrite

I have write some logs in to locally. when logs count reached 200 then only I convert the logs into JSON to upload to server. Its worked perfectly.

My thought is I am also have one flush button the flush button control the remaining data or logs that means if the logs count is 240. The first 200 logs are automatically upload to server then remaining 40 logs are manually upload to server it means when user click the flus button it will be converted to JSON upload to server.

If user when view did load click the flush button 200 logs are uploaded and then overwriting 200 logs + 40 logs to be uploaded. How can I handle this issue.

Comment: Are you deleting entries from the log on the client side once they are successfully uploaded to the server?

Comment: @alanduncan Yes. when the data is uploaded successfully to server I delete the entries otherwise maintain locally

Comment: So if a client-side log entry is removed as soon as it is successfully uploaded, how is it available for the flush button to overwrite it?  Since we don't know the implementation details, I would just generically say that some sort of lock-out mechanism between the manual upload and the automatic upload functionality is required to prevent simultaneous automatic upload and manual flush actions.

Comment: @alanduncan I mean that automatically and manually uploaded to server simultaneously that time only overwriting the data how to over come the issue.

Comment: @alanduncan if i set the time interval for flush button action..This solution is correct?

Comment: That would be one solution.  Another would be to explicitly disable the flush button during the upload operation.  This solution would make it more deterministic than a timer would.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16539/discussion-between-skm-and-alan-duncan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//URLConnection Class create the method for cancel the connection when the data upload automatically

```
NSURLConnection *Connection;
-(void)cancelConnection{
if (connection)
{
    [connection cancel];
    connection = nil;
}

}
```

//Call this method at your Button Action

```
-(IBAction)flushButtonAction:(id)sender{

[urlConnection cancelConnection];
 //call your upload method again

}
```

this button action should help to when your data uploading into server to stop that connection then create to connection to upload the remaining data.. it seems to avoid the overwriting the existing data.

Thanks for every one